# Finding all duplicates in a prolog list

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates

I have written the following code, which finds the first duplicate in a given list and 'returns' it as L, how do I make this 'return' all duplicates in the list as L?
Ex. duplicate(L,[1,2,3,3,4,4]). Would return L = 3, L = 4.

```
duplicate(_,[]).
duplicate(L,[H|T]) :-
    member(H,T),
    L is H.
```

Comment: What do you think the semantics of `L is H` is?

Comment: Furthermore I doubt whether it finds the *first* duplicate: it looks whether the *first* element is a duplicate.